# Is there an uncertainty in spacetime at Planck length due to uncertainty principle? And if so, what causes it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, spacetime, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-gravity

I understand that trying to measure particles precisely for different variables simultaneously at subatomic scales is impossible due to uncertainty principle. Does it also hold true for spacetime curvature at Planck length?

Comment: there’s no problem in measuring position.  There’s a problem with measuring position *and* momentum *simultaneously*.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero That’s what i meant actually but worded it a little too poorly. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: We have no idea, GR and QFT are not unified.